# Building a data structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Am am trying to build a data structure by looping over an array.
This is what I have

```
a = ['a1', 'a2']

def func(name)
  {name =>
   {'key1'=> 'value2',
    'key2'=> 'value2'
   }
  }
end

content = {'root'=> 
            a.each do | v |
             func(v)
            end
          }
```

Which gives me

```
{"root"=>["a1","a2"]}
```

I am after this

```
{
  "r"=> {
    "a1"=> {
      "key1"=> "value2",
      "key2"=> "value2"
    },
    "a2"=> {
      "key1"=> "value2",
      "key2"=> "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is exactly your purpose? What problem do you solve?

Answer (score 2):

You're using [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each), which only return the array itself. Instead of that, you need to use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
content = { 'root' =>
  a.map do | v |
    func(v)
  end
}
```

Or in a better syntax, since the block is one line:

```
content = {
  'root' => a.map { |v| func(v) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It still needs some refactoring but you will get the idea. If you use map it will return array and resulted "r" will be array and not hash.

```
{"r": a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) 
  { |h1, h2| h2[h1]={"key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value2"} }
}
```

it will return exactly

```
{:r=>{
     "a1"=>{"key1"=>"value2", "key2"=>"value2"}, 
     "a2"=>{"key1"=>"value2","key2"=>"value2"}
     }
}
```